# Getting Error on python post request [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

Tags: python, json, exception, ssl

Getting Error on python post request:

> [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

```
import requests
import json


url = https://URL

payload = "{'data' : 'mydata'}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
try:
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers={'Connection':'close'}, data=payload, verify=False, timeout=10)

    print(response.text)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: @Brian.Tompsett string for payload is not closed.